# Clarification regarding OpenTSDB's data model

Tags: hbase, time-series, opentsdb

I'm working with OpenTSDB for a school project. In the project I am supposed to create a structure for storing time series data from robots. The data is collected at a rate of 5 times per second, per robot and there can be up to a 100 active robots.

I've managed to set up OpenTSDB and link it to a HBase cluster. However after reading the documentation on [openTSDB's website](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/index.html#) I feel I have no clear view of the data model. The website says that every time series data point requires the following data:

- metric
- timestamp
- value
- tag(s) - Key/value

This brings me to my first question. What is the `value`? Why is it needed?

Going back to the robots; each robot is identified by two ID's and each measurement consist of a total of 9 values. Hence each measurement is associated with a total of 11 values/tags. Putting this together with the need for a metric, value and a UnixTimestamp it amounts to a total of 14 tags in OpenTSDB. The default setup of OpenTSDB doesn't support that many values. I know that the number of tags can be increased by changing OpenTSDB's configuration file, but the internet has also told me that increasing the number of tags can dramatically [slow down queries](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opentsdb/7oalcJYBVb0).

Any suggestions on how I should tackle this? Should I just increase the number of tags? Or is there another way to solve this?

Note: *All the values associated with a measurement will always be accessed and plotted together.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I just realized OpenTSDB can only plot one value per metric - and that is the purpose of the value...stupid me :)

My original thought was that the tags (key/value) could be used as values to plot. But the tags only provide search criteria for the actual value. So if you have a similar structure to me you would have to store the values in separate metrics and associate the value with the robot. In JSon it would look something like this:

```
{"metric": "value1", "timestamp": 1429542213, "value": 10, "tags":            
{"robotName": 1}}
{"metric": "value2", "timestamp": 1429542213, "value": 20, "tags":            
{"robotName": 1}}
// value 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

This means that for each one of my robots measurements I need to store 9 different time series. Since each robot sends data 5 times per second this amounts to a total of 45 time series per second, per robot. If I wish to have 100 active robots this will amount to 4500 metrics per second.